# How to recover deleted git projects

Tags: git

I wanted to merge a git branch named `gh-pages` with the master branch, but instead I typed `ph-` and pressed the tab button for autocompleted. I tried that several times, and when I looked into the folder, nothing was there Only the `.git` folder and the `Readme.md` file are left.

I have checked the log by running `git reflog`, and I can still see all the commits I have done.
Please how do I recover the files?

Comment: What shows `git status` at this point? If the folders are managed by `git`, you can recover the last state know by Git. Local changes that were not committed to Git are lost.

Comment: @EricPlaton it says branch is up to date with origin/master, that working directory is clean

Comment: `git reset --hard` should do the trick.

Comment: Were the folders really "managed by Git" ? I mean, were any of them committed to Git at some point (issued `git commit`)? You can recover them only if they were committed once. Resetting or checking out will not do anything if the folders were untracked.

Comment: @Cactus I've tried that, doesn't work. it says ** HEAD is now at d1a70fd Initial commit** , but I still can't get the folders

Comment: What says `git ls-files`? It lists all the files "managed by Git".

Comment: @EricPlaton they were all managed by git. the git repo is still there. `git ls-files` returns README.md. it is the only file left undeleted

Comment: Could you detail more what you have done? The repository may still be there, but if the files you are trying to recover were not registered at list once, they're gone.

Comment: I suggest looking at the reflog

Comment: @EricPlaton I wanted to merge a git branch named `gh-pages` with the master branch, but instead I typed `ph` and pressed the tab button for autocompleted. I tried that several times, and when I looked into the folder, nothing was there.

Comment: @eddiewould i checked reflog, all the commits I'd done are listed. Please I do I recover the files?

Comment: Please edit the question itself with the series of commands. Your question lacks context if you want to get a concrete answer.

Comment: You should add to your question the output of `git status`, `git branch -vv`, `git ls-files` and relevant part of `git reflog`. It would be also helpful if we could see exacly what commands you executed (e.g. if you are on linux bash shell you can find them in `~/.bash_history` file).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see yet how you got there, as merging a branch that does not exist leads to an error message. Here is a typical scenario:

```
$ git init metest
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/metest/.git/
$ cd metest
$ echo "file1" >> file1
$ git add file1
$ git commit -m "File 1"
[master (root-commit) 5f56a1d] File1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
$ git checkout -b some
Switched to a new branch 'some'
$ echo "file2" > file2
$ git add file2
$ git commit -m "File2"
[some 47af0d5] File2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file2
$ git log # Shows 2 commits
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git log # Shows 1 commit
$ git merge foo- # Tab completion should show nothing
merge: foo- - not something we can merge
```

There may be a bug in the Git version you are using, or in one of the satellite tools.

Anyway, assuming your remote is pristine (you did not push the changes), you can:

- `git checkout .` to recover the files. This would work if `git status` was showing some local changes.
- `git reset` and its flavors, depending on your particular case (see help).
- Clone the remote into a new directory to see if the files are there.